# How i can parsing json object with retrofit and recyclerView

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm using GitHub API to show in my application the most starred repository and their names and avatar and description in recyclerView but when I lunch the app everything working but the avatar_url and login return Null.

this is a JSON from Github API

> https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:%3E2019-10-01&sort=stars&order=desc

**I tried this :
client class:**

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class Client {
    public static final String BASE_URL="https://api.github.com";
    public static Retrofit retrofit=null;

    public static Retrofit getClient()
    {
        if(retrofit==null)
        {
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**Service Class:**

```
package com.example.gethubapi.api;

import com.example.gethubapi.model.ItemResponse;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface Service {

    @GET("/search/repositories?q=created:>2017-10-22&sort=stars&order=desc&page=2")
    Call<ItemResponse> getItems();
}
```

**Item class**
**here is the problem if u checked the jSON file in link above you will find a child object from item called owner and i cant select the name of avatar_url and owner name directly**

```
 import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Item {
        @SerializedName("avatar_url")
        @Expose
        private String avatarUrl;

        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        private String name;

        @SerializedName("description")
        @Expose
        private String description;

        @SerializedName("login")
        @Expose
        private String owner;

        @SerializedName("stargazers_count")
        @Expose
        private int stargazers;

        public Item(String avatar_url,String name,String description,String owner,int stargazers )
        {
            this.avatarUrl=avatar_url;
            this.name=name;
            this.description=description;
            this.owner=owner;
            this.stargazers=stargazers;

        }
        public String getAvatarUrl()
        {
            return avatarUrl;
        }
        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public String getDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }
        public String getOwner()
        {
            return owner;
        }
        public int getStargazers()
        {
            return stargazers;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the JSON response, the Owner object is part of the Item object. meaning it's nested in the Item object.

```
public class Owner {
@SerializedName("avatar_url")
@Expose
private String avatarUrl;

@SerializedName("login")
@Expose
 private String login;

 public Owner(){}

 public void setAvatarUrl(String avatar_URL){
 this.avatarUrl = avatar_URL;
 }

 pubic String getAvatarUrl(){
 return avatarUrl;
 }

 public String getLogin(){
  return login;
 }

 public void setLogin(String login){
  this.login = login;}
  }

public class Item {
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("owner")
    @Expose
    private Owner owner;

     @SerializedName("stargazers_count")
    @Expose
    private int stargazers;
    .........
    }
```

Comment: but what I can do in Item constructor

Comment: public Item(String name,String description, Owner owner,int stargazers )
        {
            this.name=name;
            this.description=description;
            this.owner=owner;
            this.stargazers=stargazers;

        }

Answer (score 0):

Since the login and avatar_url is under owner object.
You need to create a separate class for owner object , just like you did for a single item.
And don't forget to mention the object class in your Item class.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the stargazer spelling was wrong, just correct the spelling
example:- from

> stargazer_count

to

> stargazers_count.